# IntelliJ Cannot Import sbt Project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, sbt

I have upgraded IntelliJ to version CE 2017.3 from a CE 2017.2.5, and now I cannot build my sbt project. The build gets stuck on the first step:

```
"Build: sync
  MyProjName: syncing...
   dump project structure from sbt"
```

I have deleted the .idea directory and the the `MyProjName/project/target` directory. I did an sbt build from the command line, which worked.
Then I started IntelliJ again and tried to import `MyProjName/build.sbt` as a project. I have also logged out/in. Did this several times. The import never progresses past this step.

I work behind a firewall, but I have checked my proxy settings, and they are correct and unchanged from the previous version (if this matters).

How can I troubleshoot / fix this?

The sbt version is 0.13.6. Scala plugin 2017.3.10.

From the log:

```
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-173.3727.127, 27 Nov 2017 09:32)
OS: Windows 7 (6.1, amd64) 
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b6 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
JVM: 25.152-b6 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
```

Comment: what is the previous version of your idea . I have 2017.2.6. Aslo let us know the sbt, scala, java version.

Comment: Also, try to update scala plugin. The #2017.3.10 build have a couple of sbt related fixes.

Comment: For me it took almost an hour to go beyond this step on Ultimate 2017.3

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Glad to know that I am not alone. I will wait for an hour and two to see if moves past this step.

Comment: Thanks @fR0DDY, I had to wait for two hours before it finished. Thanks for the tip that waiting is required for it to work.

Comment: Mine exited in error after 11.5h. I will uninstall 2017.3 and try the previous version.

Comment: Maybe this is related https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13147

Comment: Radu, have you tried using the "sbt shell" import option? In my experience it's been faster in 2017.3 than the regular import. And you can see the output scroll by and see what it's stuck on (using the Build tab that will appear in the lower left).

Comment: FYI, a new IntelliJ is out. Maybe give it a whirl? 2017.3.3

Comment: Nope, still takes ages to import a large multi-module project.

Comment: On 2017.3.4, also took a long time to finish.

Comment: I am facing this same issue every time when I do fresh install of IntelliJ

Comment: I guess heaven is where sbt import is instant.

Answer (score 95):

I solved the sync issue following info here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13024

Key info is "It seems that sbt is trying to re-resolve 'sources' and 'docs' for sbt plugins that are not available at all. If properties to download "Library sources" and "sbt sources" are disabled, then time to dump the structure is reduced from 'forever' to less than 1 minute."

That is , in IntelliJ IDEA, clear the check box "Library sources" under "Project level settings" for Build Tools sbt in IDEA preferences. As shown in image below:

[image]

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me on community edition 2017.3.4

Comment: This worked for me on community edition 2017.3.4 on a 3G hotspot

Comment: This worked on 2018.1, just as a reminder you can still download sources when accessing its references(which for me looks faster as i will download them by demand).

Comment: Worked on 2018.1.4.

Comment: Works on 2019.1 for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked on 2019.2.4. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The only way I could work around this was by running `sbt clean compile` in the SBT console/cmd line first, then refreshing the SBT project in IntelliJ.

Comment: I have installed the latest 2017.3.3 (built 2018-01-15), and opened my project. It has started "dumping project structure from sbt", so I stopped that process and tried "clean compile" in the sbt console. Error: "No valid parser available"

Comment: Refreshing can be done by clicking File -> Synchronize

Answer (score 11):

- Open a terminal inside IDEA by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> or use **sbt shell**
- Run `sbt` - if it is first time it will take some time.
- Run `clean`
- Run `compile` - it will download dependencies you have in your project.
- Close IDEA project (`File` -> `Close Project`) and open it again.

**Note:** if it asks to import in the right-bottom of the screen activate `Enable auto-import`, if you don't like to keep it enabled (like me) press `Import`, cancel the syncronyzation and then `Refresh sbt project` again. When you try to use import in the middle of a sync it gets stuck with **dump project structure from sbt** message.

The `Refresh sbt project` is located at this corner of the Build Sync window - highlighted below:
[image: Refresh sbt project]

Comment: This is working solution. This should be mark for answer.

Answer (score 6):

I have not found a way to make this work in IntelliJ Idea CE 2017.3, so I have reverted to CE 2017.2.5

Comment: I added a new answer to this question. Let me know if what worked for me helps.

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ appears to limit the efficiency of the already slow `sbt update`. I recommend using [sbt-coursier](https://github.com/coursier/coursier) instead. It was written specifically to improve dependency update time, and on one large project I'm involved in it improved dependency update time by about 2 orders of magnitude.

1. Uncheck "Use auto-import" in `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > sbt` to prevent IntelliJ from auto updating imports on its own

[image]

2. Add `addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.3")` to your project's `build.sbt` file

   - Or install it globally in `~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/build.sbt`
3. Run `sbt update` on the command line

If you see `[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vafer/jdeb/Console`, then add the following to `~/.sbt/1.0/sbt-coursier.sbt`.

```
import coursier.Keys._
classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"
```

<sub>See [coursier issue #450](https://github.com/coursier/coursier/issues/450) for more information about that error.</sub>

4. (Optional) Re-enable auto-import from step 1, as subsequent transactional dependency updates may be faster.

Answer (score 4):

I meet the same problem！ I delete the directory ~/.sbt/0.13, then it works. You can delete the sbt directory you used.

Comment: I just tried that, and for me it made no difference

Comment: After deleteing I also increased the max heap as suggested in marios anwser. Then it took about 10 minutes (first time). I don't know if changing the Max heap helped or not.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to increase the memory for SBT inside IntelliJ. On my Mac: preference -> Build, Execution, Depoyment -> sbt 
then change "Maximum heap size" from 768MB to 2048MB and then everything was successfully imported after few minutes.

Comment: I have installed the latest 2017.3.3 (built 2018-01-15), and set the max heap to 4096 Mb. It still cannot finish "dumping project structure from sbt"

Comment: Could take a while the first time. How long did you wait?

Comment: 10-20 min (this time). The previous time I installed 2017.3 I waited 11h. So I don't have a lot of patience for this particular bug. I have re-installed 2017.2 and it worked right away.

Comment: I did delete the `.sbt/0.13/` dir. Then it took about 10 minutes (first time). I don't know if changing the Max heap helped or not.

Comment: now that you mentioned it, I also deleted .sbt/0.13/. probably the deletion and the increase in memory did the work.

Answer (score 2):

Custom SBT version works for me.

> IntelliJ IDEA Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> sbt -> Launcher

Choose Custom

[image: custom sbt screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

For me, simply checking `use sbt shell for both build and imports` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had an older checked out project causing this issue. Did the usual `rm -rf .idea` + re-import but it kept getting stuck. Tried all sorts of things, but when finally fixed it for me was not just deleting the top-level `target` folder, but instead doing

```
find . -name target -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Next open / import went flawlessly.  (This was on 2018.1.5, 2018.1.6 and 2018.2 RC.)

Answer (score 0):

I have suffered from same problems after upgrade intelliJ to 2017.3
But it works fine now.

I think intelliJ couldn't pass the '*No proxy for*' option to sbt.
so, I added

> -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="host1|host2"

option in **File > Settings > Build, Excution, Deployment > sbt > VM parameters**

Answer (score 0):

Simply unchecking 'sbt sources' did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. Below two configurations worked for me. I tried to confirm this setting in many new sbt projects, for all it worked.

(1) uncheck "Library sources" under "Project level settings" for Build Tools sbt in 
    IDEA preferences
(2) -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="host1|host2"
    option in File > Settings > Build, Excution, Deployment > sbt > VM parameters

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar issue but found it's related to waiting for locks

- ~/.sbt/tool/sbt.boot.lock
- ~/.ivy2/.sbt.ivy.lock

Maybe if killing IntelliJ IDEA and no one will release the lock files, the issue is resolved after deleting locks files manually