# Intellij Idea: sbt refresh FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts npm-4.2.0-sources.jar: not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sbt

When using Intellij idea with sbt, I got error:

```
[error] (updateSbtClassifiers) lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.error.FetchError$DownloadingArtifacts: Error fetching artifacts:
[error] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/npm/4.2.0/npm-4.2.0-sources.jar: not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/npm/4.2.0/npm-4.2.0-sources.jar
```

Intellij Idea Version: 2018.1 (yes I know it's old, but probably happened on newer version too)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an (currently) [open issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5501) for that.

I'm not quite sure why is this happening, probably [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697141/intellij-cannot-import-sbt-project/48473825#48473825) would explain **Why** is this happening.

But to summarize there's an answer that works for me on that thread.

```
...
I think I solved the issue. In IntelliJ IDEA, go to 
Preferences => Build, Execution, Deployment => 
Build Tools => sbt => sbt projects. 

Untick "Library sources" & "sbt sources".

I tested it on 2019.3.4 & 2020.1. Both versions work correctly.
...
```

Hope this help others :)